# STORE output to a single CSV?

Tags: apache-pig

Currently, when I STORE into HDFS, it creates many part files.

Is there any way to store out to a single CSV file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this in a few ways:

- To set the number of reducers for all Pig opeations, you can use the `default_parallel` property - but this means every single step will use a single reducer, decreasing throughput:

  `set default_parallel 1;`
- Prior to calling STORE, if one of the operations execute is (COGROUP, CROSS, DISTINCT, GROUP, JOIN (inner), JOIN (outer), and ORDER BY), then you can use the `PARALLEL 1` keyword to denote the use of a single reducer to complete that command:

  `GROUP a BY grp PARALLEL 1;`

See [Pig Cookbook - Parallel Features](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/cookbook.html#Use+the+Parallel+Features) for more information

Comment: I don't think this is ideal since you might get out of memory error with too few reducers on large output data.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use Hadoop's getmerge command to merge all those part-* files.
This is only possible if you run your Pig scripts from the Pig shell (and not from Java).

This as an advantage over the proposed solution: as you can still use several reducers to process your data, so your job may run faster, especially if each reducer output few data.

```
grunt> fs -getmerge  <Pig output file> <local file>
```