# Export from pig to CSV

Tags: excel, csv, apache-pig

I'm having a lot of trouble getting data out of pig and into a CSV that I can use in Excel or SQL (or R or SPSS etc etc) without a lot of manipulation ...

I've tried using the following function:

```
STORE pig_object INTO '/Users/Name/Folder/pig_object.csv'
    USING CSVExcelStorage(',','NO_MULTILINE','WINDOWS');
```

It creates the folder with that name with lots of part-m-0000# files.  I can later join them all up using cat part* > filename.csv but there's no header which means I have to put it in manually.

I've read that PigStorageSchema is supposed to create another bit with a header but it doesn't seem to work at all, eg, I get the same result as if it's just stored, no header file:
STORE pig_object INTO '/Users/Name/Folder/pig_object' 
USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.PigStorageSchema();

(I've tried this in both local and mapreduce mode).

Is there any way of getting the data out of Pig into a simple CSV file without these multiple steps?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't a one-liner which does the job,but you can come up with the followings (Pig v0.10.0):

```
A = load '/user/hadoop/csvinput/somedata.txt' using PigStorage(',') 
      as (firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray, age:int, location:chararray);
store A into '/user/hadoop/csvoutput' using PigStorage('\t','-schema');
```

When [PigStorage](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html) takes '`-schema`' it will create a '`.pig_schema`' and a '`.pig_header`' in the output directory. Then you have to merge '`.pig_header`' with '`part-x-xxxxx`' :

**1.** If result need to by copied to the local disk:

```
hadoop fs -rm /user/hadoop/csvoutput/.pig_schema
hadoop fs -getmerge /user/hadoop/csvoutput ./output.csv
```

(Since `-getmerge` takes an input directory you need to get rid of `.pig_schema` first)

**2.** Storing the result on HDFS:

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/hadoop/csvoutput/.pig_header 
  /user/hadoop/csvoutput/part-x-xxxxx | 
    hadoop fs -put - /user/hadoop/csvoutput/result/output.csv
```

For further reference you might also have a look at these posts:
[STORE output to a single CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910908/store-output-to-a-single-csv)
[How can I concatenate two files in hadoop into one using Hadoop FS shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607716/how-can-i-concatenate-two-files-in-hadoop-into-one-using-hadoop-fs-shell)

Comment: Thanks very much for your assistance, Lorand. Calling the shell commands cleans things up a bit.  However, the -schema argument doesn't create the .pig_header or .pig_schema files when I run it.  I've tried using PigStorage and PigStorageSchema.  I am running Pig 0.10.0.

Comment: Hi mate, further to this ...  the .pig_header file _is_ created but it was hidden and I couldn't see it (I'm still getting used to working with shell stuff).  So, I do have a workaround that can be done within script which is awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: @Saxivore Check the schema of `pig_object.` If there isn't any there won't be created any header and schema files. Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: @Saxivore why wouldn't you make this as "best answer"?

Comment: @LorandBendig the PigStore() is creating binary part files is there a way to get text files. So that when we use getmarge it will be is readable cvs format

Answer (score 2):

if you will store your data as `PigStorage` on HDFS and then merge it using `-getmerge -nl`:

```
STORE pig_object INTO '/user/hadoop/csvoutput/pig_object'
    using PigStorage('\t','-schema');
fs -getmerge -nl /user/hadoop/csvoutput/pig_object  /Users/Name/Folder/pig_object.csv;
```

[Docs:](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge)

> Optionally -nl can be set to enable adding a newline character (LF) at
>   the end of each file.

you will have a single TSV/CSV file with the following structure:

```
1 - header
2 - empty line
3 - pig schema
4 - empty line
5 - 1st line of DATA
6 - 2nd line of DATA
...
```

so we can simply remove lines `[2,3,4]` using AWK:

```
awk 'NR==1 || NR>4 {print}' /Users/Name/Folder/pig_object.csv > /Users/Name/Folder/pig_object_clean.csv
```