# ToDate function in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am having an input file with date as one of the columns. while loading data i mentioned it is chararray. I want to change this into date format using ToDate(userstring, format) function .
My date is in dd/mm/yyyy format. Script is as below,

```
mydata = load '/testinput' using PigStorage(';') as (pdate:chararray, time:chararray, gpower:double, sm1: double, sm2:double, sm3:double);

getdate = foreach mydata generate ToDate(pdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), time, gpower, sm1, sm2, sm3;
```

This is giving me error with error code 1066.

Can anybody please help me to get the issue resolved.

Comment: what is you version of pig?

Comment: Hi, the version i am using is Pig 0.12.0

Comment: can you show some sample input? also pig uses java simpledateformat for todate, mm should hence be MM.

Comment: Fred below is the sample data,

Comment: Date;Time;Global_active_power;Sub_metering_1;Sub_metering_2;Sub_metering_3
16/12/2006;17:24:00;4.216;0.000;1.000;17.000

Comment: Let me try with MM option for month.

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get rid of the header in the first line of your input.

Also, you should use `dd/MM/yyyy` as a date format (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Fred, while processing I am removing header. I kept it for reference. I tried with the option mentioned by you and it is working fine now. Thank you very much :). 
I have one more doubt if you can help me. I wrote header into other file while processing. But I am not able to append the header while writing to output file. I used ‘union’ function to merge header and data value but the header is going into bottom. Is there any function we can add the header?

Comment: please accept my answer if it did help you. for your other question, please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696036/export-from-pig-to-csv

Comment: I had tried the option PigStorage('\t','-schema') earlier but it doesnt help me as it stores header part seperately. I wanted header as first record :(.

Comment: as explained in the answer: what you'll want to do is to issue a `hadoop fs -getmerge /user/hadoop/csvoutput ./output.csv` from your pigscript.