# how to load/export CSV/TSV files from Pig to Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-pig, cloudera

I am using Apache PIG to process some data, and at the end of my script I use

```
store data into  '/mypath/tempp2' using PigStorage('\t','-schema');
fs -getmerge /mypath/tempp2  /localpath/data.tsv;
```

That way I have a `tsv` file that I readable with `read_csv(headers=0)` in Pandas.

The problem is that the `tsv` file now contains the headers on the first row (which is nice) but also the schema concatenated to the first observation in the second row such as:

```
col1             col2      col3     
{pigschema}0     1         2
```

assuming the first row is `[0,1,2]`. So unless I use `skiprows=1` in `read_csv` (losing that row), I get this weird observation in my data.

So I wonder if there is a better way to export my data, while getting the headers.

Many thanks!

Comment: May be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696036/export-from-pig-to-csv

Comment: thanks! link is pretty old so i hope there is a better solution now

Comment: also, I dont really care about the format (csv or other jsons) as long as I can load it into pandas and get the right headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you want to use `-nl` parameter for `-getmerge`:

```
store data into  '/mypath/tempp2' using PigStorage('\t','-schema');
fs -getmerge -nl /mypath/tempp2  /localpath/data.tsv;
```

[Docs:](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge)

> Optionally -nl can be set to enable adding a newline character (LF) at
>   the end of each file.

then you'll have in your `/localpath/data.tsv` the following structure:

```
0 - headerline
1 - empty line
2 - PIG schema
3 - empty line
4 - 1-st line of DATA
5 - 2-nd line of DATA
...
```

so now you can easily read it in pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/localpath/data.tsv', sep='\t', skiprows=[1,2,3])
```

Comment: excellent! but do you know how should I modify accordingly my `STORE` line in PIG?

Comment: @Noobie, FYI - i just have updated my answer - added `-nl`

Comment: @Noobie, did it help?

Comment: @Noobie, glad i could help. PS i never played with PIG before, so it was a great opportunity to try it and to learn something new