# Storing pig output into a csv file

Tags: apache-pig

I have a csv file which i am using as an input to the Pig Script. THe CSV has data like

> 1045 966 320189
>       1048  555 714067
>       1035  199 975050
>       1026  748 814808
>       1018  656 103141
>       1004  186 686093
>       1016  292 553100
>       1043  864 750624
>       1050  839 785765
>       1002  454 452221
>       1041  807 330616
>       1019  538 680915
>       1002  950 583977
>       1036  638 111509
>       1031  687 876615

My script---

```
REGISTER /home/user/myudfs.jar;
A = LOAS 'new.csv' using PigStorage(',');
STORE A INTO '/home/user/result.csv'
USING CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'WINDOWS');
```

I have a myudfs jar having the builtin class `CSVExcelStorage`. I am registering it in my script.

While executing the script, I am getting an error

```
"ERROR 1070: Could not resolve myudfs.CSVExcelStorage using imports: [,org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]"
```

Please help.

Comment: You can try these solutions :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696036/export-from-pig-to-csv  &  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910908/store-output-to-a-single-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created the UDF class under a package, then in the PIG script you should give the fully qualified name of the UDF class, that is

```
STORE A INTO '/home/user/result.csv'
USING HereGoesThePackageName.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'WINDOWS');
```